# Implicit Integrating Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have the ODE given below and am told to first find a suitable integrating factor to obtain an implicit solution $F(x,y)=C$ and then solving explicitly for $x$.

$y  - 3y^3 = \left(y^4 + 2x\right)y'$ , $y(0)=1$

I shuffled the terms around to get:

$\frac{dy}{dx}+y(\frac{3y^2-1}{y^4+2x})=0$

Then found the integrating factor by doing

$u=e^{^\int\frac{3y^2-1}{y^4+2x}}=e^\frac{(3y^2-1)(ln|y^4+2x|)}{2}$

$e^\frac{(3y^2-1)(ln|y^4+2x|)}{2}y=C$

Then taking $ln$ of both sides and shuffling terms around to finally get:

$x=\frac{e^\frac{2ln|y|}{1-3y^2}-y^4}{2}$

However, this answer is wrong. Is my method wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y  - 3y^3 = \left(y^4 + 2x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}$$ 
Your calculus is wrong. You wrote :
$$u=e^{\int\frac{3y^2-1}{y^4+2x}}$$
which is non-sens because it is not specified to which variable $x$ , or $y$ , or both related, the integration has to be carried out.

Note that $\int\frac{3y^2-1}{y^4+2x}dx \neq \frac{(3y^2-1)(ln|y^4+2x|)}{2}$ because $y(x)$ is not constant.

A more direct approach is to consider the inverse function $x(y)$ . The ODE becomes :
$$(y - 3y^3)x'-2x = y^4 $$ 
This is a first order linear ODE that you can solve with the standard method.

If you don't see it at first, change of variables : $X=y$ and $Y=x$ which leads to 
$$(X-3X^3)=(X^4+2Y)\frac{dX}{dY} \quad\to\quad (X-3X^3)\frac{dY}{dX}-2Y=X^4$$
The solution is :
$$x=\frac{y^4}{2-6y^2}+C\frac{y^2}{1-3y^2}$$
I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: I knew there was something wrong with treating $y$ as a constant. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that if you want to solve $(y-3y^3)dx-(y^4+2x)dy=0$ with the method of integrating factor, the integrating factor is $\frac{1}{y^3}$ .